# XCode fails to build WHEN device is not plugged in - ld: framework not found

Tags: ios, xcode, capacitor, cicd

New to the iOS development here. I'm currently having a hybrid application that builds and works via xcode when uploading it on a device. However, when I try to build it via command line (without any physical device as a target) like this:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${ROOTFOLDER}/App/App.xcworkspace -scheme "${SCHEME}" clean archive -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos -archivePath ${ROOTFOLDER}/build/App.xcarchive ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
```

It fails with the following error:

```
ld: framework not found AppsFlyerLib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Again, this only happens when doing it via command line without any physical device selected which makes me think that it might be some configurations issues.

Any help/tips is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are on a Mac intel then I suppose that you are not building it for the correct architecture . Check the command line that is used by the compiler and linker when building for device

Comment: @PtitXav Xac How can I do that?..

Comment: You can go in xCode , in your project window in left column (where the is project navigator , issue navigator) select the right one (Report navigator).  In the list you will find the build . Select it and in the main tab look for the link line. Click on the (list) icon on the right of the line. This will show you the ld command and it’s parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it! The actual issue was that `armv7` architecture was included as target as well. Switched to `arm64` only and got solved.